# DataBinding in WPF: getter not being called when TextBox empty

Tags: c#, wpf

I haven't done WPF for about three years now so I'm struggling a little bit. Must read a book at the weekend!

I have a problem in that the databinding is not working when the last character is deleted from my TextBox. I have other dependent properties that are subsequently not being updated.

How do I cause the binding to function when the TextBox is empty?

Thanks in advance!

M

Comment: @is the text box item source set in VM.Can you use  base.OnPropertyChanged("Count");

Comment: Are you sure it is not working?  I bet you just have not moved focus to another UI element for the binding to call. Try  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"

Comment: Nope. It's still not working. My update trigger was already PropertyChanged.